# What is the best Firebase FunctionsErrorCode for insufficient balance?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the list of Firebase functions error code

```
FunctionsErrorCode = "ok" | "cancelled" | "unknown" | "invalid-argument" | "deadline-exceeded" | "not-found" | "already-exists" | "permission-denied" | "resource-exhausted" | "failed-precondition" | "aborted" | "out-of-range" | "unimplemented" | "internal" | "unavailable" | "data-loss" | "unauthenticated";
```

When "insufficient balance" happens, what FunctionsErrorCode we should use? Is it **aborted** or **failed-precondition** or **invalid-arguments**?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that list from, but since these seem based on HTTP status codes, would this be an option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/402?

Comment: I got from pressing left Click + Ctrl and see the values. It also documented here but I am not sure which one i should use for this case. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Enums/FIRFunctionsErrorCode

Comment: Note that the documentation you link specifically says it's for "Callable HTTPS tigger", so you should not feel yourself bound to it for other types. There seems to be no enum for a 402 response in that [proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto#L26), so I'd probably go for a (more generic) 400 response, which the proto maps to `INVALID_ARGUMENT`.

Comment: After reading more, i got more confusion about failed-precondition and invalid-argument. Which one is the most suitable for this case?

Comment: As Frank suggested in the 2nd comment, it seems valid right? Can you check on that once again.

Comment: Yes, it seems good. You may add it as answer and I will mark it as accepted answer if you want @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you link specifically says it's for "Callable HTTPS tigger", so you should not feel yourself bound to it for other types.

There seems to be no enum for a 402 response in that proto though, so I'd probably go for a (more generic) 400 response, which the proto maps to INVALID_ARGUMENT.